# (Grading vs Rating vs Marking) Which one fits better when its about a number?

Tags: word-choice

Please check the wording below.

How would you mark/rate/grade me from 1 to 10?

*(By **"How"** I am asking about the number he is going to give me not the process.)*

Comment: Better ask: *on the scale of 10, what rank you'd give me?"

Answer (score 1):

"Rate" is the right answer, i.e., according to the context.

If you are using mark/grade, then, you must instead say:

"What grade/no. of marks are you going to give me?"

Answer (score 1):

Or a better question would be:

*Where would you place me in terms of **rating on a scale from 1 to 10** or **grading on a scale from 1 to 10** or **marking on a scale from 1 to 10** ?*.

This way, any of the above mentioned options can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think, though keep in mind that I am not a native speaker of English:

- *Grading* is *evaluating*. You usually grade a report, a test, an exam, etc.
- *Marking* is putting the actual score on the exam, test, whatever after having *graded* it.
- *Rating* is used in a broader sense than *grading*, but means about the same.